# Perl XML: How to Preserve white space in xml self closing tags?

Tags: xml, perl

I am working on XML file to read and write data's using the perl script, these xml files have the self-closing elements like  which have spaces in them, these spaces are removed and changed to  or  when used empty_tags=>'html'.
Is there any way to preserve the white space ?

**XML Sample: "test.xml"**

```
<article>
<title>This is title</title>
<p>Name:<tab /></p>
<p>Department:<tab /></p>
</article>
```

**Perl code:**

```
use warnings;
use utf8;
use XML::Twig;

my $xmlname = "test.xml";
my $twigdoc = XML::Twig->new(empty_tags=>'html');
$twigdoc->parsefile($xmlname);
$twigdoc->print;
exit()
```

Comment: An `empty_tags` set to `'html'` only adds the space for single-tag **XHTML** elements, not arbitrary empty ones. I don't *think* there's a way to do what you want with XML::Twig.

Comment: Also, don't use `use utf8` unless your source file is encoded using UTF-8 and has non-ASCII characters in it. https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html

Comment: Why do you want to preserve this space? It's not syntactically relevant. All of `<foo></foo>`, `<foo   />`, `<foo />` and `<foo/>` are equivalent in XML and most HTML versions. Unless the consumer of this data is so badly non-standard that things break for them, you might be wasting time on something irrelevant.

Comment: This XML is used by a old application which accepts only when these spaces are retained, I have to pass this xml to that application using the perl script, hence i'm trying to retain the space in perl.

Comment: @dasanb — The whole point of XML is that it is standard and any XML parser can parse it. Fix the consuming application so it can handle XML instead of trying to hack all the tools which generate XML so they generate it with a whole bunch of extra, pointless rules.

Comment: Simply asking this, there is a 'preservewhitespace = true' in .net is there anything we can do like that in perl ???, Please note that i'm just looking for a possibility for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

### You don't

You are concerned about a difference that makes no difference to conforming XML processors.

And if you have a consumer of XML data that is sensitive to such a difference, then that consuming application is ***broken and should be fixed***.  You should not perpetuate *its* problem by attempting to solve it as *your* problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot change the consumer. I've been there. It is frustrating.

In these cases you need to remember that you're doing Perl, and Perl is good at text processing. XML is text. Text can be manipulated with regular expressions. And as long as you don't try to **parse** XML with a regex you're golden. Let's be pragmatic.

Once you've run your code above, your output looks like this.

```
<article><title>This is title</title><p>Name:<tab></tab></p><p>Department:<tab></tab></p></article>
```

Let's forget for a moment that this is XML data that has a structure and makes sense. If we don't know this, it's just a stream of text. Text that contains

```
<tab></tab>
```

but we actually want it to contain

```
<tab />
```

So what do we do? We regex it out!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twigdoc = XML::Twig->new(
  empty_tags    => 'html',
  output_filter => sub {
    $_[0] =~ s{<tab></tab>}{<tab />}gr;
  }
);
$twigdoc->parse(<<'XML');
<article>
<title>This is title</title>
<p>Name:<tab /></p>
<p>Department:<tab /></p>
</article>
XML

$twigdoc->print;
```

This code makes use of the [`output_filter` functionality that XML::Twig provides](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#output_filter). It can take a subroutine reference, so it's trivial to do this substitution.

We can even be sure that we won't break anything with this. If the content contains `<tab/>` it will be encoded: `&lt;tab/&gt;`. Only if there was a [`CDATA` section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) we'd get in trouble if that happened to contain this, and it should not be changed.

But I would take that risk.

Comment: This was the last option i have used it, though the xml parser doesn't care about the spaces. I was just trying to figure out the ways in perl. but .net have options to handle such cases.